# Python exchangelib recurrence events

Tags: python, exchange-server, exchangelib

I use exchangelib for work with Exchange API. When I try get all events from calendar I don't get recurrence events, only master recurrence event without next occurrences. May be someone know how to get   all occurrences. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurring calendar items in Exchange are only stored as one single item containing all necessary occurrence information. This is the default item that exchangelib returns.

To get unfolded recurring items, use the `.view()` method. See https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#searching

```
unfolded_items = account.calendar.view(start=some_dt, end=some_other_dt)
```